# Expand the following expression : $\frac{1}{(x+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)})}+\frac{x}{(\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)} (x+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}))}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

I have the following expression :

$$\frac{1}{(x+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)})}+\frac{x}{(\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)} (x+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}))}$$

I don't understand why :

$$\frac{1}{(x+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)})}+\frac{x}{(\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)} (x+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}))}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

I tried I got this :

$$\frac{1}{(x+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)})}+\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}*\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Yet, I don't get the required result which is : $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

I don't understand what I missing in the expanding process.
Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: It's easy. you are almost done. Try a little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try. $$\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} + \frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\left( 1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right) = \frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$

Comment: Oh I see it now, thank you! :)